# ASP.NET Identity2 - How to get User Id with AllowAnonymous Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I would like to save in a database(date and user) who views a web page  that can be accessed by a authorized and anonymous users. Is there a way to make an action to work with both types because if the action is `[AllowAnonymous]`, the user is not authenticated and I can't retrieve the user id and if the action is `[Authorize]` the anonymous users can't access the page.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}/Detail")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ResponseType(typeof(JsonArticleDetail))]
public IHttpActionResult GetArticle(int id)
{
    ...
    var entity = this.DbContext.Articles.Find(id);
    var applicationUserId = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.GetUserId() : null;

    entity.ArticleViews.Add(new ArticleView
    {
        ViewedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
        ApplicationUserId = applicationUserId
    });

    this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(article);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? code you show should work.

Comment: but is user logged-in at that point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to have both `[AllowAnonymous]` and `[Authorize]`on the action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Authorize]
public IHttpActionResult GetArticle(int id)
```

Comment: Very interesting, I will try this, thanks! It's funny because [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0): "`[AllowAnonymous]` bypasses all authorization statements. If you combine `[AllowAnonymous]` and any `[Authorize]` attribute, the `[Authorize]` attributes are ignored. For example if you apply [AllowAnonymous] at the controller level, any `[Authorize]` attributes on the same controller (or on any action within it) is ignored." which implies the `[Authorize]` is ineffective, but you prove it's very useful!